# SwiftUI Error Code "Generic parameter 'C0' could not be inferred"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been working on some SUI code and I keep getting this error:

```
Generic parameter 'C0' could not be inferred
```

Here's the snippet it's from. I've been hunting relentlessly online, but can't find anything concrete. There don't seem to be any syntax errors elsewhere in the file, and I've tried the classic "off and on again" trick several time.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var eliminationModel = EliminationModel()
    @State private var code: String = "0000"
    let roboto = UIFont(name: "Roboto Mono", size: UIFont.systemFontSize)


    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            VStack() {
                HStack() {
                    VStack() {
                        Text("CODE:")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 15))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("6969")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 10))
                            .padding(.top, 10.0)

                        Button(action: {
                            EliminationModel.printTest()
                        }) {
                            Text("Button")
                        }
                    }

                    .padding(.horizontal, CGFloat(50.0))

                    VStack() {

                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        Text("INPUT: \(code)")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: CGFloat(20)))

                    }
                }
                .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 20.0)
                Spacer()
                HStack() {
                    VStack() {
                        Text("YOUR TARGET IS: ")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 25))
                            .padding(.bottom, 11.0)
                        Text("JOHN APPLESEED")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 40))
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Image("headshot")
                            .cornerRadius(10.0)
                    }
                }//hs
                Spacer()

                HStack() {
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("GRADE: ")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 15))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("FACULTY")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 20))

                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("DORM: ")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 15))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("DAY")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: CGFloat(20)!))

                    }
                } //hs
                Spacer()

            }

            .frame(minWidth: CGFloat(0)!, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: CGFloat(0)!, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
        } // zstack
    } // body view
} // struct

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And this is the `eliminationModel` file:

```
import Foundation

struct EliminationModel {

func printTest() {
    print("hello world")
}

}
```

Comment: Errors in SwiftUI are not always shown where they really are. Add some more code, please. for example: what is ```eliminationModel```? Do you have something other in ```body```?

Comment: I've narrowed down the error to somewhere else- getting rid of comment code hiding the rest of the body fixed brought the error back, this time saying the parameter is "S". Also, it's complaining about one of the `.font`s, saying that `Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'CGFloat?'`. Any ideas? Really starting to think that this whole SwiftUI thing isn't worth the trouble. I'll edit the main post with the whole file anyway.

Comment: SwiftUI is worth it, you just need to be a little more careful. @Rob Napier already took your example apart and I think I have nothing to add

Comment: My advice is to start using git. You can always go back to a working version, and then add functionality to see where the error comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
EliminationModel.printTest()
```

`printTest` is an instance method:

```
EliminationModel().printTest()
```

---

The `CGFloat(0)!` references are not legal, since `CGFloat(0)` is not optional. (There's also no need for the `CGFloat()` in any of this code.)

```
.frame(minWidth: 0)!, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: CGFloat(0)!, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
```

This line should be:

```
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
```

(Though I'm not sure you need to set `minWidth` and `minHeight` to 0 here.)

---

This modifier is not attached to anything; it seems to be a typo:

```
.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

---

And another incorrect `CGFloat(Int)!`:

```
.font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: CGFloat(20)!))
```

This should be:

```
.font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 20))
```

---

The way I debugged this was by repeatedly using Cmd-Shift-A>Extract Subview to make the Views smaller. Having one massive View is very hard for the compiler to type-check, and it tends to point you to the wrong line.

Putting it all back together is this (but I recommend refactoring it into smaller views.)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var eliminationModel = EliminationModel()
    @State private var code: String = "0000"
    let roboto = UIFont(name: "Roboto Mono", size: UIFont.systemFontSize)


    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            VStack() {
                HStack() {
                    VStack() {
                        Text("CODE:")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 15))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("6969")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 10))
                            .padding(.top, 10.0)

                        Button(action: {
                            EliminationModel().printTest()
                        }) {
                            Text("Button")
                        }
                    }

                    .padding(.horizontal, 50)

                    VStack() {

                        // FIXME: Unclear what this is supposed to be part of
//                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        Text("INPUT: \(code)")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 20))

                    }
                }
                .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 20.0)
                Spacer()
                HStack() {
                    VStack() {
                        Text("YOUR TARGET IS: ")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 25))
                            .padding(.bottom, 11.0)
                        Text("JOHN APPLESEED")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 40))
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Image("headshot")
                            .cornerRadius(10.0)
                    }
                }//hs
                Spacer()

                HStack() {
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("GRADE: ")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 15))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("FACULTY")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 20))
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("DORM: ")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 15))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("DAY")
                            .font(Font.custom("Roboto Mono", size: 20))

                    }
                } //hs
                Spacer()

            }

            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        } // zstack
    } // body view
} // struct
```